# Perl Dancer, Dancer::Plugin::DirectoryView, Template Toolkit and sharing params in templates

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, param, dancer

I have a post route which is returning params for use in a specific template (actions.tt). Within that template, I'm loading a div (using jQuery) with a view (dirmain.tt) of a directory using the DirectoryView plugin. My problem is that I need to pass a param to the DirectoryView template before rendering the main template (action.tt).The param (dev) needs to be included in the the Directory listing.

Perl portion:

```
Use Dancer;
....
post "/" => sub {
template 'actions.tt', {
    'dev' => param('dev'),
};
```

Templates:

actions.tt

```
....
<div id="dir">
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#dir').load('/files/[% dev %]');
    </script>
</div>
....
```

dirmain.tt

```
....
how do I pass [% dev %] here before the action.tt is rendered by the browser?
....
```

Would using a hook of some sort fulfill this?
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Rendered"? By the browser? Or before `actions.tt` is compiled by Perl (which wouldn't make much sense)? Anyway, I don't know Dancer, but you probably want to access `session->uri()` in your template (setup to access it somehow), or if that wouldn't work for some reason, you could pass value of `dev` as some parameter when requesting, `load('/files/[% dev %]?x=[% dev %]')` and use `param "x"`. Just some random thoughts.

Comment: @Qtax I've edited the confusing part. I appreciate the tips, I ended up defining what I needed to in the DirectoryView module. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

params is a function that delivers a hash, so params("dev") won't get you anything. This is better:

```
template 'actions.tt', {
   'dev' => param->{dev},
}
```

but in Dancer, some variables like params, request and session are exported by default in the templates. So you can leave the {} after 'template' empty and use this in your template:

```
$('#dir').load('/files/[% params.dev %]');
```